How to test the arguments of a Action that is itself passed as a method argument?
I'd first like to state that I'm new to StackOverflow, unit testing with NSubtitute and to working with actions/delegates in C# - so apologies in advance for any misuse of formatting and/or terminology.
I have the following code:
    public class Status
    {
        public Status() { }

        public enum ReceivedStatus
        {
            NotReceived = 0,
            Received = 1
        }

        public ReceivedStatus XReceived { get; set; }

        public ReceivedStatus YReceived { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IHandler
    {
        void UpdateStatus(Action<Status> update);
    }

    public class Handler : IHandler
    {
        public void UpdateStatus(Action<Status> update)
        {
            update(_status);
            //Some additional stuff with _status would probably happen here
        }

        private Status _status = new Status();
    }

    public class Sequencer
    {
        public Sequencer(IHandler handler)
        {
            _handler = handler;
        }

        public void UpdateX()
        {
            _handler.UpdateStatus(x => x.XReceived = Status.ReceivedStatus.Received);
        }

        public void UpdateY()
        {
            _handler.UpdateStatus(x => x.YReceived = Status.ReceivedStatus.Received);
        }

        IHandler _handler;
    }

I would like to write a unit test (using MSTest and/or NSubstitute) that can verify that the UpdateStatus method was called on a Handler with a particular value set on the Status that is passed in the Action argument.
I have got as far as writing the following unit test code, where I mock a Handler and pass it to a Sequencer, call the UpdateX method on the Sequencer, and then assert that the UpdateStatus method was called with an Actoin<Status> argument:
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            //Assign
            Sequencer sequencer = new Sequencer(_mockHandler);

            //Act
            sequencer.UpdateX();

            //Assert
            _mockHandler.Received().UpdateStatus(Arg.Any<Action<Status>>());
        }

        private readonly IHandler _mockHandler = Substitute.For<IHandler>();
    }

This successfully asserts that UpdateStatus was called with an Action<Status> argument. But really what I would like is to be able to assert that specifically an Action<Status> argument where "XReceived" was set to "Received" was called with the UpdateStatus method.
Any help would be much appreciated!

For now I can only see the way by inspecting the calls manually:
public void TestMethod1()
{
    // Assign
    Sequencer sequencer = new Sequencer(_mockHandler);

    // Act
    sequencer.UpdateX();

    // Assert
    // First assure we will have such invocation at all.
    _mockHandler.Received().UpdateStatus(Arg.Any<Action<Status>>());
    var action = _mockHandler.ReceivedCalls()
        .SelectMany(x => x.GetArguments())
        .OfType<Action<Status>>()
        .First();
    var status = new Status() { XReceived = Status.ReceivedStatus.NotReceived };
    action(status);
    Assert.AreEqual(status.XReceived, Status.ReceivedStatus.Received);
}

